# systemd error: (Loaded: bad-setting)

Tags: pi-3b+, raspbian-buster, systemd

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3B+ with Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (Buster) currently installed as my OS. I'm having some issues in starting a `systemd` service that will rerun a Python script whenever it stops/terminates. I'm fairly new with this kind of system in Linux and would like to ask for help with what might be the problem.

Below is the unit file I'm using which is placed in the `/etc/systemd/system` directory.

```
[Unit]
Description=Rerunning python script
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '\
   cd /home/pi/community/file_directory \
   source /home/pi/file_directory/venv/bin/activate; \
   python /home/pi/file_directory/pythonScript.py'
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s
User=pi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

At first, the unit file was working when the default version of Python was 2. So I decided to transition to Python 3 by executing these commands:

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
  #added the following lines at the bottom of the file
  alias python='/usr/bin/python3'
  alias pip=pip3
  #saved and exited
source ~/.bashrc
```

After this configuration, I started the unit file again by executing the command:
`sudo systemctl start rerunPython.service`
and got the following error:

```
Failed to start wcs1000-GCP.service: Unit wcs1000-GCP.service has a bad unit file setting.
```

Checked the error for more details with: `systemctl status rerunPython.service` and had the following information:

```
Loaded: bad-setting (Reason: Unit wcs1000-GCP.service has a bad unit file setting.)
Active: inactive (dead)
DATE_AND_TIME raspberrypi systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/rerunPython.service:5: Unbalanced quoting, ignoring: "/bin/bash -c '   cd /home/pi/file_directory source /home/pi/file_directory/venv/bin/activate; \"
DATE_AND_TIME raspberrypi systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/rerunPython.service:5: Unbalanced quoting, ignoring: "/bin/bash -c '   cd /home/pi/file_directory source /home/pi/file_directory/venv/bin/activate; \"
DATE_AND_TIME raspberrypi systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/rerunPython.service:5: Unbalanced quoting, ignoring: "/bin/bash -c ' cd /home/pi/file_directory source /home/pi/file_directory/venv/bin/activate; \"
DATE_AND_TIME raspberrypi systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/rerunPython.service:5: Unbalanced quoting, ignoring: "/bin/bash -c ' cd /home/pi/file_directory source /home/pi/file_directory/venv/bin/activate; \"
DATE_AND_TIME raspberrypi systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/rerunPython.service:5: Unbalanced quoting, ignoring: "/bin/bash -c '   cd /home/pi/file_directory source /home/pi/file_directory/venv/bin/activate; \"
DATE_AND_TIME raspberrypi systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/rerunPython.service:5: Unbalanced quoting, ignoring: "/bin/bash -c '   cd /home/pi/file_directory/ source /home/pi/file_directory/venv/bin/activate; \"
DATE_AND_TIME raspberrypi systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/rerunPython.service:5: Unbalanced quoting, ignoring: "/bin/bash -c '   cd /home/pi/file_directory/ source /home/pi/file_directory/venv/bin/activate; \"
DATE_AND_TIME raspberrypi systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/rerunPython.service:5: Unbalanced quoting, ignoring: "/bin/bash -c '   cd /home/pi/file_directory/ source /home/pi/file_directory/venv/bin/activate; \"
DATE_AND_TIME raspberrypi systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/rerunPython.service:5: Unbalanced quoting, ignoring: "/bin/bash -c '   cd /home/pi/file_directory/ source /home/pi/file_directory/venv/bin/activate; \"
DATE_AND_TIME raspberrypi systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/rerunPython.service:5: Unbalanced quoting, ignoring: "/bin/bash -c '   cd /home/pi/file_directory/ source /home/pi/file_directory/venv/bin/activate; \"
```

May I ask for help with what the error means? How did configuring the default python version to 3 affect the service? Also, please let me know if there are any improvements or more information needed about this issue. I deeply appreciate your time and understanding.

Comment: bit of a guess, but I would say that the 'unbalanced quotes' error leads to an invalid `ExecStart` which then leads to the `bad setting` error. Anyway, you'll have to sort the quotes error before anything else.

Comment: What do you think "~" means to sudo? Attempting to alias python3  violates recommended python practice and is likely to break other services. This is not Pi specific.

Comment: @Milliways I understand and thank you for your feedback. As I said I'm still a bit of a beginner in Linux systems. I am using a Raspberry Pi as my central unit in transmitting telemetry data to a cloud service.
Can I ask what's the best practice in making the default python version to 3 in a pi?

Comment: See raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour to see how this site works. There is **NO** "best practice in making the default python version to 3 in a pi" - this depends on the OS implementation - just run python3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, lets get your Unit step by step. First to the error message. It says what's wrong:

```
'   cd /home/pi/file_directory source /home/pi/file_directory/venv/bin/activate; \"
```

It starts with a single quote but do not end with one. That's the *Unbalanced quoting*. But we will not take any effort to correct the bash script because we will use systemd options to run the python script.

With the modification of `~/.bashrc` you only define aliases for **python3** so python scripts will be executed with python3 when called with python, but by default python calls the python2 interpreter. So scripts executed with python, are written for python2 and usually not executable without errors using the python3 interpreter.

So the first step is to make your script running with python3. Check it on the commandline with:

```
rpi ~$ /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/file_directory/pythonScript.py
```

and make it running without errors. You will find many tutorials on the web how to upgrade python scripts.

Then edit your Unit file with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl edit --full rerunPython.service
```

In the editor you should find your old Unit. Delete all lines and insert the following statements, save them and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
Description=Rerunning python script
After=network.target

[Service]
User=pi
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/community/file_directory
ExecStartPre=/home/pi/file_directory/venv/bin/activate
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/file_directory/pythonScript.py
Restart=on-success
RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You should not `Restart=always`. It doesn't make sense to restart a failed program, it will not fix the error. It only restarts the program again and again because mostly the error isn't temporary. You should make the python script to end successful (exit code 0) when it shall restart. For other options to `Restart=` look at `man systemd.service` and for starting the script at `man systemd.exec`. To get an idea `man systemd.directives` may be useful.